# how to use mapdispatchtostate in reudx?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, frontend

> this is file list.js

```
...
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
        ...    
          {this.props.todoList.map((todo, index) => <Item {...todo} key = {index}/>)} // err this code
        ...
    );
  }
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todoList: state.todos 
  };
};
...
```

> this is file rootReducers.js

```
const initialState = {
    todos : [
        { id: 1, name: "Khoa" },
        { id: 2, name: "Khoai" },
        { id: 3, name: "Kha" }
      ],
      currentName : ''
}

const TodoList = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return [...state.todos, { id: state.todos.length + 1, name: action.text }];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
...
```

> this is action.js

```
export const addTodo = (text) =>{
    return {
        type : 'ADD_TODO',
        text
    }
}
```

> this is file fromCreate.js

```
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addTodo: (text) => dispatch(addTodo(text))
  };
};
...
```

> i'm loading data success but, when i excute event addtoto it message : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Help me

Comment: show `createStore` code

Comment: The line `id: state.todos.length + 1` will get you in a word of trouble when you implement deleting todos. You can do the folling to prevent problems: `const createId = ((counter) => counter++)(initialState.todos.length);`. When you add a todo you can do: `id:createId()`. If you plan to persist state with localstorage then you have to set the id in the middleware because the id depends on what id's are already used in your todo list.

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer code seems wrong. You need to return full new state slice from it not just an array.

```
const TodoList = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos, { id: state.todos.length + 1, name: action.text }]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```